# Assembly doesn't have a strong name

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am really stuck in providing a solution for my existing code.

I have an IBM software which was running in an older version 4.6 and we using our custom CDAutoInterop.dll (Embed Interop type = true) which was provided by IBM in 2009 and in this case my application is signed with strong name. No issues in this as it is running in live without any issues.

Upgrade: as part of Upgrade we have to use the latest version of cdAuto.dll (Embed Interop type = false) which is provided by IBM in 2020, and once I have used the dll to my application and rebuild the application, it failing as the `cdauto.dll` doesn't have a strong name.

I have tried the dll to disassemble (`ildasm`) but still I am not able to assign the strong name to `cdauto.dll`.

Comment: Possible duplicate! - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370753/reference-to-assembly-without-strong-name